# Can postman call some c# dll or custom routine before send request out?

Tags: postman

I am trying to create some postman test cases for an old web api.

What I realized is that the web api expects binary content in the HttpRequest body other than a Json message. We have a c# client, which does this before sending request:

```
var body = new ByteArrayContent( SerializeToByteArray(info));
    
using ( var result = await Client.Post<HttpResponseMessage>( options , body , Configuration , ct ).ConfigureAwait( false ) )
```

In postman, can I call a routine(either existing function or some custom dll) to convert body to byte array before sending the request out?

Answer (score 0):

No, Postman does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible directly.

What you can do is to run a (local) server, send a request to it from Postman's prerequest script, and the server then executes the binary.

An approach is drafted at the Postman community forum: https://community.postman.com/t/is-it-possible-to-execute-an-external-program-from-postman/5693/2?u=chrissbaumann